# Systemd custom service not start at boot

Tags: boot, systemd

**Ubuntu 16.04**

**In the terminal this command is ok:**

```
sudo systemctl start TestSM.service
```

the service works in manual start, but not start at boot.

**Systemd service details:**

```
[Unit]
Description=inotify

[Service]
ExecStart =/home/test/inotifySendMM

[Install]
WantedBy = multi-user.target
```

**This is the error in boot log ( journalctl -b)**:

```
ubuntuVM systemd[1010]: TestSM.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /home/test/inotifySendMM: No such file or directory
```

Comment: The error "/home/test/inotifySendMM: No such file or directory" suggests you have the wrong path to /home/test/inotifySendMM . It could be you have a separate or encypted home directory in which case you would need to put /home/test/inotifySendMM somewhere else such as /usr/local or some such.

Comment: @Panther thank you, this is the solution. I have move all in /usr/local/bin/